# « Se sentir chaud et froid », sens figuré (Via Mala, John Knittel, Albin michel p. 391)

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques

> *Via Mala*, John Knittel
>
> Elle dissimulait sciemment un assassinat; bien plus, elle protégeait les assassins. Elle se sentait chaud et froid, chaque fois qu'elle y pensait.

Le terme « chaud et froid » nomme un symptôme précurseur d'une maladie plutôt bénigne.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chaud))  Chaud et froid. Refroidissement pouvant entraîner diverses maladies (rhume, grippe, bronchite)
> L'orateur funèbre, ayant pris un chaud et froid au dernier enterrement, traînait un mauvais rhume à fièvre et à grosse toux creuse... A. Daudet, L'Évangéliste,1883, p. 278.
>
> P. métaph. En littérature, il faut arriver doucement, de peur d'attraper un chaud et froid (Renard, Journal,1895, p. 264).

Quel sens donner à « se sentir chaud et froid » ? Est-ce simplement « être terrifié »  ou peut-être seulement « être mal à l'aise » ou bien encore autre chose ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est une traduction trop littérale de l'anglais.

L'original est (de Google Books):

> She was condoning knowingly a murder, and was moreover protecting the murderers. Hot and cold went her blood when she realized it. She did not go down to meet Andi on his arrival as she would have done at any other time.

En anglais, *go hot and cold* peut signifier *avoir très peur*, et c'est comme ça que je le comprendrais dans cette phrase. [Vois la définition](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+hot+and+cold).

Comment: Ça voudrait donc bien dire « être terrifié », mais ça serait un anglicisme qui n'aurait pas pris.

Comment: C'est un peu mieux que *elle se sentait chaude et froide* mais ***chaud et froid*** ne signifie pas ça en français. J'aurais traduit cette expression par ***elle en avait des sueurs froides.***

Comment: Imo, the "and" also has an implicit temporal aspect. You don't feel these things at the same time; you rapidly feel one after the other — hot with anger or embarrassment, immediately followed by a chill of fear.